# Running Qt from launcher

Tags: linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 19, writing in C++ with the latest Qt Creator, installed with the offline downloader.

I've made an application with buttons, each of which launches a different program. It all works except for launching Qt - I can't find where the Qt executive lives, so I can't point startDetached to the right place. I've looked everywhere - in /usr/bin, in /opt (there's only google chrome in there).

Any suggestions where I might find the Qt executive?

Answer (score 1):

Found it at `~/Qt5.11.2/Tools/QtCreator/bin`.